# Service Fabric Actors: Problems when actors are deployed with newest versions of Service Fabric nuget packages

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-actor

Yesterday I created a new service fabric application, including a new Actor. When I deploy it on my local service fabric cluster, the publish has a “succeeded” status.
But the problem is when I go on the Service fabric cluster, I can see that the actor is on “Error” health state.
I can show you the error messages on the diagnostic events and the Server Fabric Explorer:

[Service Fabric Cluster Explorer [IMAGE]](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/22/2/1527582402-explorer.png)

[Diagnostic Events errors [IMAGE]](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/22/1/1527498457-sfr-errors.jpg)

To show you my problem I created a simple solution with the usual actor example created by Visual Studio that should work properly. 
I created a .Net Core 2.0 Actor Service.
[Actor Service](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/22/1/1527498625-actorservice.jpg)

The nuget packages used by the actor are:

- Microsoft.ServiceFabric (6.2.274)
- Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors (3.1.274)
- Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data (3.1.274)
- Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services (3.1.274)

My Visual Studio is on Version **15.7.2** and the Service Fabric runtime is on the latest version **6.2.274.9494** .

I also have another solution with actors that works with nuget packages with previous versions that can be deployed and working on service fabric correctly.

When I updated the service fabric package to the newest version, there were errors with the actors on the service fabric explorer.
So I can deduce that these errors can be produced by the newest version of the service fabric nuget packages.

Best Regards,

Alexandre

Comment: Make sure that, your service fabric upgrades mode set to Automatic - https://snag.gy/ROcSQ5.jpg

Comment: I don't have that option on my Local Service Fabric Cluster, the cluster installed on my own computer

Comment: The 6.2/3.1 packages are not backwards-compatible with the 6.1/3.0 SDK, this would result in the actors not starting. Can you make sure that you really are using the latest SDK and restarted the machine and cluster?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with pre 2.0.5 version of .NET Core.
Installing latest runtime (2.1.1 currently) and changing service fabric actor projects to use it fixed the issue.